# radius search with google maps and mysql in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how to write this query in laravel controller

```
SELECT *, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) + 
       COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( $lat )) * COS( RADIANS( lon ) -
       RADIANS( $long )) ) * 6380 AS distance 
FROM places
WHERE ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) + 
  COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( $lat )) * COS( RADIANS( lon ) - 
  RADIANS( $long )) ) * 6380 < 10 
ORDER BY distance
```

10 is radius in km
$lat and $long is the center or the cirlce
lat and lon are attributes if your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just implementing the haversine formula here. He's a quick scope you can attach to Models.

```
public function scopeCloseTo($query, $location, $radius = 25)
{

    /**
     * In order for this to work correctly, you need a $location object
     * with a ->latitude and ->longitude.
     */
    $haversine = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($location->latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians($location->longitude)) + sin(radians($location->latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude))))";
    return $query
        ->select(['comma','separated','list','of','your','columns'])
        ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius]);
}
```

In the above function, you can set the `$radius` as the 3rd argument, so in your case `10`.

The 2nd argument is a `location` from which you wish to find places within a radius `of`. Think of this as your starting point.

E.G.; if you want to get all places near your house. `your house` would then be passed as a `location` object as the 3rd argument, with a `longitude` and `latitude` property.

You can adjust the `radians(longitude)` to match your models table. Or you can use `this` to reference the current model, and make this reusable (which is what we opted for.

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
App\Models;

class Hairdresser extends Eloquent {
    //scopeCloseTo function in here
}
```

Finally, invoke it:

```
$hairdressers = Hairdresser::closeTo($location, 10);
```

Which will find all `Hairdressers` within `10` km of your `$location`.

Comment: this is my function

    public function scopeCloseTo($query, $lat, $lon, $radius)
    {

        $haversine =        "  ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $lat )) * COS( RADIANS( `lon` ) - RADIANS( $lon )) ) * 6380 ";


        return $query
            ->join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
            ->select(['users.name', 'users.email', 'profiles.*'])
            ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
            ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius]);
    }

Comment: this is giving me no result. what m i doing wrong. does whereraw and selectraw exist in laravel 5.2? my table name is places. my model name is place. its attributes are lat and lon

Comment: @JunaidMasood These methods for sure exist in Laravel 5.2 We've chosen to go the route we have above using `whereRaw` and `selectRaw` to avoid conflicts with the paginatination (and other) factories not working out of the box (as a side note - this will be fixed in  Laravel 5.3). Your `haversine` implementation is not the same as mine, however, your table names, `lat` and `lon` are incorrect. It should be `place.lat` and `place.lon`, and you should also be selecting those columns in your `->select([...,place.lon,place.lat,....users.name, users.email`

Comment: this is not returning anything here is how i used it `$haversine = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(c_lat)) * cos(radians(c_long) - radians($Long)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(c_lat))))";
        return $query
        ->select('email')
        ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ", [$radius]);` my table name is drivers and columns are c_lat , c_long

Comment: @Sama Do not replace the actual words **latitude** or **longitude**. Only replace, `$location->latitude` and ` $location->longitude`